# how to keep text value as it is after submit button is clicked

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp

```js
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class LoginController
{ 
 @RequestMapping(value="/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String GetL(Map<String, Object> model){
  return "login";
 }
 
 private Map<String, String> LoginMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  
    public Map<String, String> getLoginMap() {
        return LoginMap;
    }
 
    public void setLoginMap(Map<String, String> LoginMap) {
        this.LoginMap = LoginMap; 
        }
 
 @RequestMapping(value="/login.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)

 public String login(@RequestParam(value="userid", required=true) String userid,
      @RequestParam(value="password", required=true) String password,
      @RequestParam(value="confirmpassword", required=true) String confirmpassword,
      @RequestParam(value="role", required=true) String role,
      Map<String, Object> model, ServletRequest request)

{
  if(userid.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,24}$") && password.matches("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{5,15}$")
  && confirmpassword.matches("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{6,20}$") 
  && (role.equals(new String("OPS(Operational)"))||role.equals(new String("Helpdesk"))))
  
  {
      model.put("userid", userid);
      model.put("password", password);
      model.put("confirmpassword", confirmpassword);
      model.put("role", role);
      
      System.out.println("successful!");
      return "page2";
  }
  else
  {
   boolean validated = true;
   getLoginMap();
   String errors ="";
   if(userid.isEmpty())
   {
    validated = false;
    model.put("useridError","Please enter user id"); 
    System.out.println("executed");
    errors = "useridError&"; 
   }
   if(password.isEmpty())
   {
    validated = false;
    model.put("passwordError","Please enter password");
    System.out.println("executed2");
    errors.concat("passwordError&");
   } 
   if(confirmpassword.isEmpty())
   {
    validated = false;
    model.put("confirmpasswordError","Please enter confirmpassword");
    System.out.println("executed3");
    errors.concat("confirmpasswordError&");
   } 
   if(role==null || role.isEmpty())
   {
    validated = false;
    model.put("roleError","Please select one");
    System.out.println("executed4");
    errors.concat("roleError&");
   } 
   
   if(validated)
   {
    return "page2";
   }
   else
   {
    return "redirect:login.htm?"+ errors; 
   }
  } 
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ include file="include.jsp" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

<div align="center" id='formlogin' class="container">

<form  method="post" id="loginForm" name="loginForm" action="login.htm" commandName="userForm" style="margin-bottom:30%">
  <table class="tableprop" id="tableform" border="0" width="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  
  <h3> Add a new user </h3>
  
   <tr>
    <td align="center">User ID:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="5" size="20" type="text"  name="userid" id="userid"  value="<%=request.getParameter("userid")!=null?request.getParameter("userid"):""%>"></td>
    <td><c:if test="${param.useridError != null}">
      <div id="error" class="alert alert-danger">
          <font color="red"><p>Invalid UserId</p></font>
      </div></c:if></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Password:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="5" size="20" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")!=null?request.getParameter("password"):""%>"></td>
    <td><c:if test="${param.passwordError != null}">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <font color="red"><p align="inline" class="err">Incorrect Password</p></font>
      </div></c:if></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Confirm Password:</td>
    <td><input tabindex="5" size="20" type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" value="<%=request.getParameter("confirmpassword")!=null?request.getParameter("confirmpassword"):""%>"></td>
     <td><c:if test="${param.confirmpasswordError != null}">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
     <font color="red"><p>Password should be same as above</p></font>
      </div></c:if></td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center">Role:</td>
    <td><select name="role" id="role" title="Please select role" tabindex="5" value="<%=request.getParameter("role")!=null?request.getParameter("role"):""%>"></td>
     <option value="">Select a specific role</option>
     <option value="OPS(Operational)">OPS(Operational)</option>
     <option value="Helpdesk">Helpdesk</option>
     </td>
     <td><c:if test="${param.roleError != null}">
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <font color="red"><p>Please select one</p></font>
      </div></c:if></td>
     </select> 
   </tr>
   
   <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
   
   <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4"><input tabindex="7" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="submit"/></td>     
   </tr>

   </table>    
  </form>
 </div>
<script>
 // just for the demos, avoids form submit
 jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
 debug: true,
 success: "valid"
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

these two are the code `login.jsp` and `LoginController.java`
1) I want that text value should remain as it is after submit button is clicked.
Suppose, user has entered wrong password and he clicks the submit button so user id should not disappear. User id should remain as it is and message should come as password wrong. I have added value=`"<%=request.getParameter("userid")!=null?request.getParameter("userid"):""%>">` in jsp for each field. But this is not working because validation in the controller.

2) In `LoginController.java` file, I have validation which are not working. How to work them out? This is server side validation. I have client side validation as well in jquery.

Comment: i think the use of backing beans will be more helpful and the bindingResult.hasError() can be used to do whatever if errors are present and the backing bean will take care of retaining the values for you

Comment: Its ok. 1) But can I not make changes in the above code? Do I need to change the entire code? And I don't know what is backing beans . 2)Will you please give me any relevant links which relates to my code ? And I will prefer the answer of first question.

Comment: hope this forum discussion will help you http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/867692-how-retain-username-text-box

Comment: or else you are going with the spring framework look at this example http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-handling-tutorial-and-example and then look at the binding result validation here http://codetutr.com/2013/05/28/spring-mvc-form-validation/

Answer (score 2):

You can add all your attributes received in controller to session attributes so that your attributes and values will be retained in your login.jsp.

Refer this link for using @SessionAttributes in Spring

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/

Alternatively, you can use spring form backing object and store it in session

Refere this link for using spring form backing object

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

Comment: sorry sir . I m unable to do that because I havent earned total of 15 reputations.

Comment: No problem. Keep learning and be active in stackoverflow. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can add to the request attribute and retrieve[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaDzm.png) it like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcV7H.png)

Comment: Rather than the image, direct placing the code would be more helpful.